# Ubuntu 12.04 MySQL 5.5.24 Crashes Everyday

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

About once per day the MySQL daemon crashes. Restarting with `service mysql restart` or `service mysql start` produces a "job failed" message. MySQL can only be restored by rebooting the instance. Here's my.cnf:

```
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#

#
# * IMPORTANT
#   If you make changes to these settings and your system uses apparmor, you may
#   also need to also adjust /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld.
#

user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 256M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 256K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover          = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
max_connections         = 800
wait_timeout            = 180
net_read_timeout        = 30
net_write_timeout       = 30
back_log                = 128
table_cache             = 128
max_heap_table_size     = 32M

#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
#log            = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#
# Error logging goes to syslog. This is a Debian improvement :)
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
log_slow_queries        = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time         = 2
log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
# You might want to disable InnoDB to shrink the mysqld process by circa 100MB.
#skip-innodb
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M

#
# * Federated
#
# The FEDERATED storage engine is disabled since 5.0.67 by default in the .cnf files
# shipped with MySQL distributions (my-huge.cnf, my-medium.cnf, and so forth).
#
skip-federated
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 16M

#
# * NDB Cluster
#
# See /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-*/README.Debian for more information.
#
# The following configuration is read by the NDB Data Nodes (ndbd processes)
# not from the NDB Management Nodes (ndb_mgmd processes).
#
# [MYSQL_CLUSTER]
# ndb-connectstring=127.0.0.1

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

**UPDATE 1**
Here's the output of `free -t`:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        499092     492708       6384          0      10564      60928
-/+ buffers/cache:     421216      77876
Swap:       524284     481076      43208
Total:     1023376     973784      49592
```

All of the mysql logs are empty, except slow queries. None of the slow queries run longer than 0.001.

Comment: What's in your MySQL error log?

Comment: You are talking about an instance. Is it possible you are using a (OpenVZ) VM? If yes: that is an important information do add. Also add the output of `free -t`

Comment: @cperrin88 it's a Linode, not sure about OpenVZ.

Comment: @Ladadadada all the logs are empty, except slow queries.

Comment: Just to be sure, you do realise the error log goes to syslog?  MySQL writes to the error log as it is starting up and when it's ready to start working.  If your error log is empty, you're looking at the wrong file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for starters you set MySQL to use more memory than your VPS has: `key_buffer` and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` are set to a 256MB maximum each. So what happens is out of RAM -> swapping like mad -> out of swap space -> dead MySQL.

Start by reducing those 2 vars to 32M each, run MySQL for a bit, use Tuning Primer ( http://www.day32.com/MySQL/ ) to get better idea what to set and where.